# Does the Bootstrap Grid System work with navbars?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm attempting to place an element to the left of a navbar using the grid system.  However, it doesn't seem to be working very well.  The text I inserted, which is just an example, should be wrapping down after it hit the end of it's alotted grids.  However, the text seems to just keep going on.  I have included a picture to illustrate this.

Additionally, my toggle dropdown menu seems to be transparent yet still functional.  Any ideas as to how to remedy this?

[image]

Here's a link to my code:

http://pastebin.com/HfHyBYZZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you have a continuous string of letters so it won't wrap so overruns the grid.
If you put a space in it will.
Not withstanding if you create a style for the  rest like

```
  #long-letters {
  word-wrap: break-word;
   }
```

It will then respect the grid and your navbar will be fine.